# Windows Forms app looks different from Visual Studio designer view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am trying to create a Windows Forms app using Visual Studio 2017. The app should be run on a 1024x768 touchscreen eventually, that is why I am trying to make all forms in size 1024x768 and without a form border. The problem is that when I launch the app the buttons seem to shift slightly and this makes them fall partially off the screen. The text also seems to be displayed in reduced quality and/or another size. You can look at the images below as an illustration of what I mean.

This is what the form looks like in the designer view in Visual Studio. The text is clear, everything fits the screen and all text fits in the buttons
[Designer view of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erN2Z.png):

[image]

This second picture shows the form when I actually launch the app. The text quality is reduced, the 'Add From' text does not fit inside the button anymore and the bottom two buttons are partially off the form.
[View of the form when app is launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO5IG.png) :

[image]

My form is set to AutoScaleMode: Font, AutoSize: False.

Are these form parameters wrong or is it something in my Visual Studio settings? I have no clue what I could do to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try WPF, it is best for scaling and touch input\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution differences looks like a DPI issue. Windows Forms doesn't scale well to a DPI other than 100%. Check your monitor settings.
In Windows 10, this is labelled "**Change the size of text, apps, and other items**" in Display Settings.

Comment: Thank you, changing the resolution of my monitor did help and everything gets displayed correctly now!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please **accept this as the correct answer** so then it can help people in the future :)